# WPF: Managing several user controls in a window

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I am rather new in WPF and I am developing a WPF application in VB.net. I have several controls in my Main Window. As I follow the MVVM pattern, I have a `MainViewModel` for my Main Window. In this ViewModel, I instatiate my user control view models.

```
Public Class MainViewModel

    Public Property myUserControlViewModel As UserControlViewModel

    Public Sub New()
        Dim myModel As Model

        myModel = New Model(parameter)
        myUserControlViewModel = New myUserControlViewModel (myModel)

    End Sub
End Class
```

**Question1:** Is this pattern following MVVM Correctly?

**Question2:** How can I force my user control to use `myUserControlViewModel`? I mean specificly this instance which is already created in my `MainViewModel`. How should I even introduce `myUserControlViewModel` to my User Control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this pattern following MVVM Correctly?

Yes.

> How can I force my user control to use `myUserControlViewModel`?

Create a `ContentControl` in the view that binds to the `myUserControlViewModel` property and and includes a `DataTemplate` for the `UserControlViewModel` type:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding myUserControlViewModel}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserControlViewModel}">
            <local:UserControl1 />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

This will display the `UserControlViewModel` as a `UserControl1`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I actually could not get it running with ContentControl. I get this error: `UserControlViewModel is not supported in a WPF project`. 

However, your reply got me to the right direction. My mistake was that I was trying to set the data context of my user control inside of my user control. Now I defined the data context as a public property in my `MainViewModel`, and bound it to my user control.